Removable USB Flash Drive as Local HDD in Windows
I'm working on a project where I need to programmatically eject removable disks. However, some removable disks are being identified as local disks in Windows, preventing me from ejecting them. I have tried several solutions, including using a tool to flip the RMB (Removable Media Bit), but without success.
Is there a way in C# to change the identification of a local disk back to a removable disk, or to programmatically eject such disks? Any help or guidance would be appriciated!
https://woshub.com/removable-usb-flash-drive-as-local-disk-in-windows-7/

As a non-native speaker even with multiple years of experience I'm confused by your question, it has too many typos. Please [edit] it to become comprehensible.

Basically, you can't change this programmatically, especially with a language like C#. If you want to do this with your own code, you would need to use low-level languages like C or C++. However, if it is possible through Windows settings or similar, you could write a C# code that modifies the necessary setting.

C# can interop with C and can call any Win32 API so obviously it can do anything a C program can do
